# VBA format cell based on fill color and font color

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel where I have to

1. remove cell fill color if existing fill color is yellow
2. set cell text color back to black only if existing font color is red.

I have written a macro that simply loops over each cell and checks the font color / fill color

```vb
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
...
For Each Cell In ws.UsedRange.Cells
   If Cell.Font.ColorIndex = 3 Then
      Cell.Font.ColorIndex = 0
   End If
   If Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
      Cell.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
      Cell.Interior.TintAndShade = 0
      Cell.Interior.PatternTintAndShade = 0
   End If
Next
```

It works as expected but it runs very slowly probably because it goes through each cell. Is there a to make this work faster ? I tried using conditional formatting with VBA but it cant seem to check for the cell color / cell font color...

Comment: You can try `ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Cells` ... Assuming there are no formulas in the cells, you can change this in the If For Loop.

Comment: Also adding `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` in the beginning of the code and `True` in the end will make it significantly faster.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No Need to **loop**. You can search and replace using colors. Try this

**Remove cell fill color if existing fill color is yellow**

```
With Application.FindFormat.Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 65535
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
With Application.ReplaceFormat.Interior
    .Pattern = xlNone
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
Cells.Replace What:="", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True, ReplaceFormat:=True
```

If you had to do this manually, you would have done this

[image]

Similarly for the font.

**Set cell text color back to black only if existing font color is red.**

```
With Application.FindFormat.Font
    .Subscript = False
    .Color = 255
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
With Application.ReplaceFormat.Font
    .Subscript = False
    .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Cells.Replace What:="", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True, ReplaceFormat:=True
```

If you had to do this manually, you would have done this

[image]

**Note**: The VBA `Find` uses parameters. Except `What:=`, rest of the parameters are optional. It is recommended that you provide those parameters. If you don’t, then `Find` will use the existing settings. If you do not want to provide the optional parameters then it is a must to clear those parameters before you use `Find` else you will get undesired results. You can do that by `Application.FindFormat.Clear`

Similarly `Replace` uses parameters and if you do not want to provide the optional parameters then clear them using `Application.ReplaceFormat.Clear`

Comment: + For a usefull technique. I used it myself so now and then and found that you would need to use `Application.FindFormat.Clear` and `Application.ReplaceFormat.Clear` to make this run properly if you use it more than once (or the two scripts after each other), because at least with me, the formats don't just clear but stay (you can check in the Find/Replace window). I normally used those lines right before and after the code.

Comment: Yes **.Find** retains the settings and needs to be reset..  I am on the road right now. Will include that in my answer in couple of hours :)