# VBA code to delete cells that contain a certain fill color?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, foreach, delete-row

I am new to VBA and am trying to delete cells that have a certain fill color. I cannot delete the entire row with cells that have fills because that would delete data that I need. I am trying to use a loop, but it does not delete all the cells that contain the fill color I specify, only some towards the top of my spreadsheet. If I run the macro several times, it will end up deleting all the cells with the color that I specified.

```
Range("A1:AF150").Select
For Each cell In Selection
    If cell.Interior.Color = RGB(112, 48, 160) Then
        cell.Delete
    End If
Next cell
```

Comment: Do you want to **delete and shift up** or **delete and shift to the left** or merely **clear** the cell ???

Comment: `Delete` or `Clear` ? Seems strange to delete a cell. Generally it's a row.

Comment: I would suggest using clear contents; delete will shift the cells upwards

Comment: You can use [.Find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57684943/vba-format-cell-based-on-fill-color-and-font-color/57685092#57685092) and `.FindNext` rather than using a For Each Loop... and collect all the cells using `Union`. Then in the end, simply delete all the cells in one go...

Comment: If you still want to use a `For Loop` then collect all the cells using Union. Then in the end, simply delete all the cells in one go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because when cell is deleted, data below shifts up and the loop goes to the next cell, omitting the one that just shifted up.

It's not possible to loop backwards using for each loop, but you can do it this way:

```
Set rng = Range("A1:AF150")
For i = rng.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
    With rng.Item(i)
        If .Interior.Color = RGB(112, 48, 160) Then .Delete
    End With
Next
```

Also I would suggest setting a workbook object.

Also, are you sure you want to delete and not clear cell?

Comment: thank you this was very helpful. Ideally, there are some rows that contain this color but also columns that also contain this color that I need to delete. So I cannot delete the entire row if one cell in the row contains the color because there are columns that contain the color so everything would end up getting deleted. So I'm just deleting it by cell

Comment: What I mean is if you .delete cell, all data beneath will be moved each time, whilst if you .ClearContents, it will clear any data entered in the cell but not move any other cells. You might want to change it's color to xlNone as well after clearing. If I helped, please don't forget to mark it as correct answer :)