# Find cells with yellow color

Tags: excel, vba

I need your assistance with a macro can identify if there is a yellow cells (vbYellow) with certain range

```
Dim dataset As Range
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set dataset = Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(lastrow, 30))
'I need something like:
if there is vbYellow in Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(lastrow, 30)) then msgbog "Please correct error"
Else "No error found"
```

Comment: Is the cell marked formatted with yellow or via conditional formatting? And is it always the same yellow?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57684943/vba-format-cell-based-on-fill-color-and-font-color/57685092#57685092

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what You are looking for:

```
Sub findyellow()

Dim dataset As Range
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim cell As Range
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set dataset = Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(lastrow, 30))

For Each cell In dataset.Cells

    If cell.Interior.Color = vbYellow Then
        MsgBox "Please correct error in cell (" & cell.Row & " " & cell.Column & ")"
        Exit Sub
    End If

Next

MsgBox "No error found"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you wouldn't want to loop potentially (depending on lastrow in column A) thousands of cells, you could try the inbuild `SearchFormat` and check if there is any cells that are still yellow:

```
Sub Tst()

Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, lr As Long
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")'Change accordingly
    Application.FindFormat.Clear
    Application.FindFormat.Interior.Color = vbYellow
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng1 = .Range(.Cells(1, 3), .Cells(lr, 30))
    Set rng2 = rng1.Find(What:="", SearchFormat:=True)
    If Not rng2 Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Please correct error"
    Else
        'All good
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

`.Find()` will return `Nothing` if no cells are found that fullfill the `SearchFormat` criteria.