# VBA that will pull a formula down until it hits a blue cell?

Tags: excel, vba

Is that possible? In cell B5 I put the number 1, then in B6 I put =B5 + 1 so that it reads 2, then I want that formula to go down until the end of the report which results in a row of blue cells. However, our reports always have a different number of lines.

Basically, the report runs out with a total line at the bottom, which is filled with dark blue.  I want to, in column B, count how many rows until we hit that blue cell.  There is no value or text in the blue cell though.

My code:

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveCell.Range("A1:A182")
```

Comment: Yes it's possible - what have you tried so far?

Comment: While recording a macro, I did what I mentioned above.  Unfortunately when I run that macro on a report with a different amount of lines, it only has the amount of when I was recording.  I tried using relative references but still came out with : Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveCell.Range("A1:A182").  The report I tried it on only had 50 rows, but in the column I'm counting in it still went all the way down to 182

Comment: I was given the advise of clicking the black cross that auto-fills formulas, but the result was the same as above.

Comment: What is the RGB of this "color blue" can u provide a screenshot of it?

Comment: I can't seem to add a screenshot, but the values are Red 93, Green 123, and Blue 157

Comment: Unfortunately unable to put together an answer. But have a look into the `Range.Find` function. You can set it to look for a specific format, read color. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57960380/9758194) for some inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

This would search the first 10,000 rows for the "blue row", then set a value to that row number - then autofill from `B5` to that row:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim i As Long, bluerow As Long

    For i = 1 To 10000
        If Cells(i, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(93, 123, 157) Then
            bluerow = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

    Range("B6").AutoFill Destination:=Range("B6:B" & bluerow), Type:=xlFillDefault

End Sub
```

Comment: I can't seem to add a screenshot, but the values are Red 93, Green 123, and Blue 157

Comment: Hmm all it seems to do is fill all of the cells with a light blue color.

Comment: Definitely a possibility Dwirony, but when you got the time, have a look at SearchFormat instead of a cumbersome iteration. Should save tons of time.

Comment: SearchFormat looks promising.  I'll play around with dwirony's code and SearchFormat when I get back in in the morning.  Thanks guys, hopefully this can be figured out.

Comment: @JvdV Good call, I've never had to use that before :)