# Change the value of a cell according to the font colour of another cell

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I would like to change the value of a cell depending on the font color of another cell.

In three adjacent columns I have three different values. On one of the cells I have a value with green font.

I would like to make a condition that depending on which cell contains text/values with green font I can select the column where this text is located:
[image]

I tried to create a function to find the color of the font then use this function in an if statement.

```vb
Function IsColor(lColor As Long, cl As Range) As Boolean
If cl.Font.ColorIndex = lColor Then
    IsColor = True
Else
    IsColor = False
End If
End Function
```

Comment: You could use the `Find` method - it has a format parameter.

Comment: Can you illustrate your answer with an example?

Comment: What if there is green text in both "B" and "C", do you want to show "B" or "B, C"?

Comment: What's the reason for these colours? In case they are produced by conditional formatting, it might be a better idea to base your column on the conditional formatting source than on the colours.

Comment: Be aware that `Find` does not work on conditional formatted colours: I have just created an Excel file, containing two cells, the one contained the word "Black" and the other the word "Green". I used conditional formatting to change the colour of "Green" into ... green, of course :-) When using `Find`, using font formatting font colour, nothing was found.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Dominique ! And your rigth `find` doesn't work. simple-solution's answer is the rigth solution for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using your function the following might solve your issue:

The find method is illustrated here: [VBA format cell based on fill color and font color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57684943/vba-format-cell-based-on-fill-color-and-font-color)

```vb
Option Explicit

Function IsColor(lColor As Long, cl As Range) As Boolean
If cl.Font.Color = lColor Then
    IsColor = True
Else
    IsColor = False
End If
End Function

Function findGreen(myRange As Range) As String
    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim tmpStr As String
    tmpStr = "no green color found!"
    For Each myCell In myRange
        'Debug.Print myCell.Address; myCell.Font.Color
        If IsColor(vbGreen, myCell) Then
            'Address or column ?!
            'tmpStr = myCell.Address
            tmpStr = "green in column " & Chr(64 + myCell.Column)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next myCell
    findGreen = tmpStr
End Function

Sub test_findGreen()
    Call findGreen(Range("A2:C2"))
End Sub
```

[image]